# Python subprocess: Issues capturing error where part of command fail when piped together

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe

Take a simple command in bash

```
cmd='ls -l | wc -l'
```

I understand that we can run this command several ways using subprocess call/check_output/ communicate. The problem arise for me if initial commands do not work or fail for some reason. Like  [replace ls with lsx].

```
cmd='lsx -l | wc -l'
```

In this case how can we capture error or we just have to process the output to figure out? Here is what I tried.

```
import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('lsx -l | wc -l', shell=True)
/bin/sh: lsx: command not found
       0
0
>>> subprocess.check_output('lsx -l | wc -l', shell=True)
/bin/sh: lsx: command not found
b'       0\n'
```

It seems that error code are still 0 in above two commands. 
I also tried https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline but cannot figure out how to get error code for first process.

Comment: Why not assign `stderr` to something and check if it is empty?

Comment: @Ranjit, ...it's quite possible to get the exit code when following the "replacing shell pipeline" example you link -- could you show your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `bash` instead of `sh`, you can set the `pipefail` option to return a nonzero exit status if any part of a pipeline fails:

```
subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', 'set -o  pipefail; lsx -l | wc -l'])
```

---

That said, you can certainly avoid using `shell=True` altogether:

```
import subprocess
try:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '--invalid-argument'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    wc_stdout = p2.communicate()[0]
    if p1.wait() != 0 or p2.wait() != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Something failed!")
except FileNotFoundError as ex:
    raise RuntimeError("Something failed, because we couldn't find an executable!") from ex
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. When I try valid argument, the program is still reporting error like changing line 3 to p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: Heh -- you're right; p1.returncode is `None`, not `0`. Thanks, I'll fix that up.

Comment: @RanjitKumar Now calling `wait()` for both processes explicitly, so that no longer happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `stderr` to PIPE. Consider this example:

```
>>> from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
>>> sub = Popen('lsx -l | wc -l', shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> output, error_output = sub.communicate()
>>> error_output
b'/bin/sh: 1: lsx: not found\n'
>>> output
b'0\n'
>>> sub = Popen('ls -l | wc -l', shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> output, error_output = sub.communicate()
>>> error_output
b''
```

Comment: stderr isn't exclusive to errors -- POSIX specifies that it be used for *all* diagnostic logging. Anything that isn't output intended to be piped to other programs belongs there, so it's where status bars and the like are conventionally printed. Consequently, "stderr is non-empty -> must be a failure" isn't a safe assumption to make in the general case. See [Do progress reports / logging information belong on stderr or stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331611/do-progress-reports-logging-information-belong-on-stderr-or-stdout)